# Raspberry Pi remote desktop

Tags: rdp, lxsession

I would like to control raspberry pi from remote desktop. I tried to use Microsoft remote desktop from my android phone, and it works fine. however I want that I will be able to log on the same session that shown on the raspberry pi screen, that's mean I want to get the same screen on my phone and on the raspberry pi. Is there a way to do that? can any one help please!

Comment: So, it's called a "remote desktop" and you want to view *linux* from *android*.  You will notice the Google Play Store has a **Search** feature, **as does the internet itself**.  However, do not get your hopes up as this would require software on the pi too, which has an obscure architecture, and e.g. [teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/news/291-Android-App-TeamViewer-Free-is-now-available-on-the-Android-Market.aspx), which appears to dominate this niche for Android, doesn't have an rpi implementation.

Comment: Oh but: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/02/connecting-via-vnc-to-raspberry-pi-from.html <- Somebody's done it via tightVNC. Good luck and if you find something that works, please come back and answer your own question.

Comment: thanx goldilocks ! but as I said in my post, I want to get the same display on the HDMI screen and on the Android. on that tutorial, it gave another xsession so another display! what I want to do is to have the same display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I'm aware of that lets you connect to the same session that is on a local screen is X11VNC, "a VNC server for real X displays". What you'll need is X11VNC on the Pi and some form of VNC client on your remote device.

Install X11VNC

> sudo apt-get update 
>  
>   sudo apt-get install x11vnc

Set a password (you can skip it but probably don't want to)

> x11vnc -storepasswd

It'll prompt you for a password.

Next, ensure that you've already got a desktop running.
Now we can start X11VNC.

A basic start, this will wait for a connection and then close itself when you disconnect. We also tell it to use password, go to background after starting (so you can still use the console) and to show display :0 (0 is a fairly safe assumption but it might be something different.)

> x11vnc -usepw -bg -display :0

If you want it to stay active and listen for connection you can instead use this.

> x11vnc -usepw -bg -forever -display :0

Now it's just a matter of connecting with a VNC client by specifying hostname/IP and the screen number, exactly how that's done depends on the client. I've got no recommendations for a VNC client on Android but I'm sure there are many to choose from.

Comment: Thanx a lot @Leonick !

Comment: that worked for me as I wanted!  actually  want to go far with this by doing the inverse; that's mean I want to display my pc screen or phone screen on raspberry pi! is there a solution for that?

Comment: Yup. You'd just do the reverse, run a VNC server on the PC or the Android device and a client on the Pi.

TightVNC is a good server for Windows and it'll show the active session with no real configuration, just start and set a password.

No idea about servers for Android except I they exist.

Xtightvncviewer is one client for the Pi.

Answer (score 0):

To expand somewhat on Leonick's answer, there's a full tutorial here:
http://log.liminastudio.com/writing/tutorials/remote-desktop-control-of-a-raspberry-pi

Comment: I'm not sure this constitutes as an answer.